# Gentoo installation WiFi issues after rebooting what to install in chroot

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, gentoo

I'm installing Gentoo. Last time I tried my wifi was not working, so this time I want to make sure I get it right.

I'm done with this step:

```
emerge --ask --verbose --update --deep --newuse @world
```

But I think that I have to install networkmanager, wpa-supplicant, wirelesstools and netctl (like Arch Linux).

If it is correct, when do I do it (before configuring the kernel or after), or if it is wrong then what packages do I install and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already identified the correct driver of your wifi device. If not, you can find help [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Wifi). Sometimes, compiling it as a **module** instead of built-in can help. It also helps in situations when resuming from hibernate.

Emerging `net-misc/networkmanager` with the `wifi`-useflag should be fine after the kernel has loaded the wifi device driver. You can check/pretend how portage would install networkmanager the folliwing way:

```
emerge -pav net-misc/networkmanager
```

If you see a `wifi` without a `-` in front of it, you should be good to go. Note, that some window managers have useflags enabled by default, that install networkmanager for you. Then it would be better to add `-1/--oneshot` to the parameter list of the emerge-command above, so that it will not be recorded in your world file.

Btw., I had generally good experience, installing Gentoo with ethernet plugged in and deal with wifi after the window manager is installed. But if you want to use a window manager that does not provide a GUI to configure it, I would suggest looking at the option presented in the **Gentoo handbook** [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Tools#Optional:_Install_wireless_networking_tools) and [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Networking/Wireless).

Comment: I see, looking back the issue was that I did not install the backend `wpa_supplicant`. Thank you for the help.